# Itextsharp PDF getting Corrupted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext

I am working on this feature which takes a pdf from a database and signs the PDF with an image of the signature which needs to be retrieved from the database. I am using `iTextSharp` for this, but somehow it is not working and is corrupting my PDF in the database.

This is the code of my controller

```
public ActionResult Approve(int? id)
{
    ApplicationUser users = db.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    Reports reports = db.Reports.Find(id);

    if (reports == null || users == null) return View();

    byte[] content = reports.Content;
    byte[] signature = users.Signature; 

    iTextSharp.text.Image sigImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(signature);

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(content);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);

        sigImg.SetAbsolutePosition(0f,0f);

        sigImg.ScalePercent(90.0f); // 100.0f == same size


        //Give some space after the image
        sigImg.SpacingAfter = 1f;
        sigImg.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM;

        PdfContentByte over = stamper.GetOverContent(1);

        over.AddImage(sigImg);

        reports.Content = ms.ToArray();
        content = reports.Content;

        ms.Flush();
        db.SaveChanges();
        if(stamper!= null)
            stamper.Close();
        if(reader!= null)
            reader.Close();

        return File(content, "application/pdf");

        // Clean up

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You retrieve the contents of the `MemoryStream`

```
reports.Content = ms.ToArray();
```

before you close the `PdfStamper`

```
if(stamper!= null)
    stamper.Close();
```

which means the `MemoryStream` does not yet contain the complete stamped PDF.

Thus, change the order of commands, in particular close the `stamper` before retrieving the bytes from `ms`.

As an aside: Why do you check `stamper!= null`? It obviously cannot be `null` there...

Comment: Thanks and can you also please tell me what does ms.flush() does?

Comment: A `flush` of a `MemoryStream`... I would assume that essentially is a NOP... a no-operation call. A `flush` makes sense in any stream with an internal buffer before content is written to the target medium, but not with a `MemoryStream` where RAM memory already is the target medium.